# How can a vampire kill a ghost or something connected to the Umbral world?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade, wraith-the-oblivion, umbra

I am playing with my friends a combined version of Vampire. In that world there are some werewolves, ghosts, and other creatures. I have a mission to make some people stop believing in ghosts and make them believe in the power of blood. I was thinking about summoning one ghost and killing him. Is it possible by the book?

Comment: Welcome! You can take the [tour] as an introduction to the site and check the [help] if you need further guidance. Good luck and happy gaming!

Comment: Why would you killing ghosts make other people stop believing in ghosts? You should be setting up fake hauntings and then revealing them, to make ordinary people think anything a "ghost" does is just a hoax.

Comment: @ObliviousSage I had in mind that that will show them power of blood and weakness of ghosts. Let say those people believe ghosts are responsible for everything, weather, seasons, life and death, all kinds of spirits. I must destroy blind faith and show them power of true vampire.

Comment: Do you want them to believe that ghosts are *weak*, or that ghosts are *not real*? Wouldn't visibly summoning a ghost and destroying it break the Masquerade?

Comment: @ObliviousSage both approaches will work for me. Setting which I am playing allows me to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with the mechanics of Wraith: The Oblivion, but [this forum post](http://forum.theonyxpath.com/forum/main-category/main-forum/the-classic-world-of-darkness/wraith-the-oblivion/842218-how-to-kill-a-wraith-or-a-spectre/page2) shares this information:

> Page 58 of The Sea of Shadows:
>
> "If all or most of the damage was normal (i.e., not aggravated), the
>   above holds true. If a wraith loses all her corpus due to aggravated
>   damage, there is no Harrowing; the wraith is dead forever. Aggravated
>   damage is caused by a power of Moliate, when the wraith is Embodied,
>   or by Stygian of darksteel weapons."

So if "[Deathlords and high-ranking Hierarchy officials](https://whitewolf.fandom.com/wiki/Embody)" appear in the physical world using Embody, you can **throw any aggravated damage at them** and it would work. But if you're targeting a run-of-the-mill average ghost, it's unlikely that they'll be able to cross over.

Or you could get your hands on **a [stygian steel](https://whitewolf.fandom.com/wiki/Stygian_steel) weapon** that was created in the Underworld and somehow brought over into the Skinlands. This is something that I'm guessing would take an absolutely extraordinary backstory to justify or a storyteller ruling that a necromancer using the power Ex Nihilo is allowed to enter the Underworld, grab an object, and bring it back with them. The rules for Ex Nihilo don't mention whether or not this is possible.

You could instead cast the level five **Thaumaturgy ritual Warding Circle Versus Spirits / Ghosts**, which would create the effect of banishing any spirits in a particular area, like a haunted house. With some subterfuge, that could be presented as a character "killing" those ghosts.

You could also use the **Necromancy power Compel Soul** and, on an exceptionally high roll, force a ghost to do something that puts it "in immediate peril of destruction", like stay inside of a Warding Circle.

The wording of the **Necromancy power "Haunting"** says that

> A wraith attempting to leave the area of a haunting must make an
>   extended Willpower roll (difficulty 9, four cumulative successes
>   necessary in a single scene) or take a level of aggravated damage for
>   each roll. If the wraith runs out of health levels, it is hurled deep
>   into the Underworld to face destruction.

so you could theoretically both bind a wraith in place with Haunting and then use Compel Soul to force it to try to leave the area of effect and be destroyed in the process.

The **Necromancy power Torment** allows a vampire to inflict lethal damage on a ghost (who is perhaps held in place with Compel Soul or Haunting), which can have the appearance of killing the ghost, but only banishes them for a month. Still, that would probably get the reaction that you wanted.

I'm sure there are plenty of other options in the World of Darkness, but that's all I could dig up from a quick glance through the V20 rulebook.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! (I see you've had an account for a while, but this is your first answer.) Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: Thank you @Phantom Watson this is really helpful

Comment: Glad to hear it! If you feel like it answers your question, you can mark this answer as being **accepted**.